# Proving the following integral is equal to 0 for any x

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm in the middle of a big problem and to get to the next part I need to prove the following:

$\int  \int_{\partial \Omega} f\nabla g- g\nabla f dA$ = 0

When $f(x)=g(x)=0$ For any $x$ belonging to $\partial\Omega$

$f$ and $ g$ Are both functions from $R^3$ to $R$, and x is a vector.

How exactly would I be able to prove this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: $\Omega$ Is 3 dimensional

Comment: I was distracted, my question was irrelevant. Check my answer and see if you get it

Answer (score 1):

$$\iint_{\partial \Omega} f\nabla g- g\nabla f\ dA = \iint_{\partial \Omega} f\nabla g\ dA - \iint_{\partial \Omega}g\nabla f\ dA$$

But $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ if $x \in \partial\Omega $.

Hence for each integral one of the functions, $f$ on the first and $g $ on the second, is always 0. This means each integral evaluates to 0.

$$\iint_{\partial \Omega} f\nabla g\ dA = \iint_{\partial \Omega} 0\nabla g\ dA = 0$$

And similarly for the second one.

One didn't even have to split the integrals. You could immediately have

$$\iint_{\partial \Omega} f\nabla g- g\nabla f\ dA = \iint_{\partial \Omega} 0\nabla g- 0\nabla f\ dA = 0$$